# Changing Image from a control in another form

Tags: c#

I have a main form that most of my interactions occur on.  I also have a another form that just has a picturbox in it.  When I click on a button on form1 I want to display the second form which I can already do.  However I am having issues setting the image to the picturebox in form2 from form1.  Here is my code

```
public Image picboximage {

        get { return pictureBox23.Image; }
        set { picboximage = value; }
    }


//in form 1

    Form2 otherform = new Form2();


    therform.picboximage = Image.FromStream(lxFS);
```

However this gives me a stackoverflow excepction on the

```
set { picboximage = value; }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: `set { picboximage23.Image = value; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "set" for your "picboximage" property, you're setting the wrong property. You are, in effect, calling the "set" over and over until the call stack overflows (which is why you're getting the exception you're getting).

Try this:

```
public Image picboximage 
{
    get { return pictureBox23.Image; }
    set { pictureBox23.Image = value; }
}
```

Comment: I changed it to that but I'm getting a blank picturebox.

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside your "set" and verify that "value" actually has a value. That is, verify that Image.FromStream(1xFS) is returning a valid value.

Comment: Since your stackoverflow exception is no longer happening, please mark my solution as the answer and submit a new question if you still can't get the image to display. You can link to it on this page.